# Passing a string array to a module

Tags: system-verilog

Can i use a string array here like this in a generate loop.
My string is this.

```
// Code your testbench here
// or browse Examples


module tb();

 string inp_filename [4] = {"file1", "file2" , "file3", "file4"};

 gen1 inst(.inp_filename(inp_filename));

endmodule
//I am using it like this

module gen1 (
  input string inp_filename[4]
);
   generate
      for (genvar i = 0; i < 3; i++) begin 
         for (genvar j=0; j < 4; j++) begin 

           module_inst 
            I_sample_gen(
                         .file_name(inp_filename[i])
                         );
         end 
      end 
   endgenerate
endmodule

module module_inst ( input string file_name);

    int file_handler , file_handler_1;
    localparam FILE_EXTENSION = ".txt";
  
  initial begin : FILE_HANDLER_I
    $display("string : %s " , file_name);
    file_handler   = $fopen({file_name , "_i"  ,  FILE_EXTENSION}, "r");
    file_handler_1 = $fopen({file_name , "_q"  ,  FILE_EXTENSION}, "r");
    if (file_handler == 0 || file_handler_1 == 0 ) begin
      $display("ERROR: Data file handler for CC was NULL, ensure file exists File_handler= %0d", file_handler);
      $display("ERROR: Data file handler_1 for CC was NULL, ensure file exists File_handler= %0d",file_handler_1);
      $finish;
   end
   end : FILE_HANDLER_I
endmodule
```

I was expecting to get a string in the generate loop but did not got it. I tried to open a file using this string but did not got anything in the string.

Comment: The file_name in the module_inst is a string and tried to open a file. But the string is empty.

Comment: I tried to open a file by using that string but did not get anything.

Comment: posted it in the code

Comment: I have changed the code please try this one. It should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in verilog no order is defined in execution of initialization or 'initial' blocks. You can think about initialization as just other initial blocks. So, one of the ways to handle it is to add a delay in the main inital block:

```
  initial begin : FILE_HANDLER_I
    #1 // <<<
    $display("string : %s " , file_name);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it solved my problem . But i don't understand what do you mean by the "You can think about initialization as just other initial blocks". Initialization also start at zero time.

Comment: logically `string inp_filename [4] = '{"file1", "file2" , "file3", "file4"};` == `string inp_filename [4]; initial   inp_filename ='{"file1", "file2" , "file3", "file4"};` Now you have multiple `initial` blocks which explains undefined order of execution between them. Note, this is different for wires, where initializations are represented by `assign` statements.